# The Instructor have 2 teaching subject

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Table

```
Instructor
    ------------------------------------------------------
    | id | firstname | lastname | subject_id | section_id |
    ------------------------------------------------------
       1    John        Smith        1             1

Subject
    -------------
    | id | name |
    -------------
      1  English
      2   Math

Section
    -------------
    | id | name |
    -------------
     1  Section A
```

My Query:

```
SELECT ins.firstname, ins.lastname,sec.name as "Section Name", sub.name as "Subject"
    FROM instructor as ins
    JOIN section as sec
    JOIN subject as sub
    WHERE ins.section_id = sec.id AND ins.subject_id = sub.id AND ins.id =1
```

Result:

```
firstname   lastname    Section Name    Subject 
John    Smith            Section A  English
```

My question is what if that instructor john smith also teaching Math subject how I am going to query that? Do I need to add new subject_id? Any solution for these?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add another table used for storing the subjects for each instructor, ex

```
CREATE TABLE Instructor
(
    ID INT,
    InstructorName VARCHAR(30),
    ..... -- other fields here
);

CREATE TABLE Subject
(
    ID INT,
    SubjectNameName VARCHAR(30),
    ..... -- other fields here
);

CREATE TABLE INSTRUCTOR_SUBJECT
(
    RecID INT,
    InstructorID INT,
    SubjectID INT,
    CONSTRAINT tc_pk PRIMARY KEY (RecID),
    CONSTRAINT tc_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (InstructorID) REFERENCES Instructor(ID),
    CONSTRAINT tc_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (SubjectID) REFERENCES Subject(ID)
);
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a578d/1)

Answer (score 0):

What you have now is a 1-to-many relationship, where an instructor can have only one subject but any subject can have multiple instructors. You want a many-to-many relationship which means adding a new table with only the `instructor_id` and the `subject_id`.